# showing the exsitence of fixed point in $\bar{D} = \{z:|z| \leq R\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

we have close circle $\bar{D} = \{z:|z| \leq R\}$ and analytic function $f$ in $\bar{D}$ that:  $f(\bar{D})\subseteq \bar{D}$.

we need to show that there is $z_0 \in \bar{D}$ that $f(z_0) = z_0$.

Rouché's theorem does not work for me here. (I don't know  that $|z| > |f(z)|$ in $|z|=R$).
I also tried to define $g(z) = z - f(z)$ and use minimum modulus principle under the assumption that $g(z) \neq 0$ , but I'm still missing something.

Any hints will be welcomed.

Comment: Well, you could use Rouche's Theorem, really: $|f(z)|=|f(z)- z + z| < |f(z)-z|+|z|$ strictly if you suppose that zeroes inexist. The contradiction follows from the Theorem, because $z$ has a zero within the states region, but we have supposed that $f(z)-z$ doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better writing down as an answer:

We will be using [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) version of Rouché's theorem.

Suppose there are no zeroes within the stated region. Thus, we've that $|f(z)|=|f(z)-z - (-z) | < |f(z)-z| + |z|$ on $\partial D = \{z; |z| = R\}$, because the LHS is bounded by $R$, and the second one must be (by compactness) greater than $R + \varepsilon$.

By our version of Rouché's Theorem, $f(z) - z$ has at least one zero in $\overline{D}$. But this clearly contradicts our assumption, and our proof is complete.

Comment: thanks. but I don't understand why you use < and not $\leq$ in the inequity ?

Comment: Because for Rouché's Theorem to hold, we have to get a strict inequality. And, as showed above, we've got this inequality.

Comment: OK. I see now. I just accustomed to write it like this: $|f(z)|=|f(z)-z - (-z) | \leq |f(z)-z| + |z|$ => $|f(z)| < |z|$, because $|f(z)-z| > 0$.

Comment: sorry.. my bad. still something not adds up here. I still can't see why using < is corrects . $|a+b| \leq $|a|+|b|$.

Comment: Let's suppose that $f(z)-z \ne 0$ always in $\overline{D}$. Then, as the latter set is compact, we've that $\inf_{z \in \overline{D}} |f(z)-z| = \varepsilon_0 > 0$. Then, we have that $|f(z)| \le R$ by assumption, and $|f(z)-z| + |z| \ge R + \varepsilon_0 > R \ge |f(z)|$.

Comment: thanks. something strange here.. as I understand according to wiki, I should be able to show that $|z| = |-z| > |f(z)|$ (returnning to the original Rouché's), but I can't do it... maybe just tired.

Comment: ahh. I see . that's stronger version of Rouché's theorem. (not just symmetric). the problem we did not learn that stronger version.

Comment: @JoãoRamos I do not get how the strict triangle inequality gives you Rouche theorem. Something is wrong here. To use Rouche the way you do you need the condition $|f(z)|<|z|$ on $\bar D$. Maybe Schwarz lemma will help to get it.

Comment: @A.G. It would be quite sad if it were true, wouldn't it? Why don't you take a look into Ullrich's *Complex Made Simple*? I learned myself the theorem stated in the wiki during my complex analysis course. We proved it, and I don't think it is wrong...

Comment: who changed the wiki ? I did found the stronger in another place (page 2) :https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01093927/document

Comment: @JoãoRamos I will have a look at it, never seen Rouche theorem as the triangle inequality.

Comment: Cool! I have found a short proof [here](http://www.researchgate.net/publication/265327051_A_remark_on_Rouches_theorem) on p. 5. Thanks for opening my eyes :D

Answer (score 1):

This is a straightforward application of [Brouwer theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouwer_fixed-point_theorem).

Comment: True, but I think the point was to avoid WMD's.